# mySql, same date same group

Tags: mysql

how to return the Result column as shown below using mySql? Same date will return same result.

INPUT:

```
date col | Desc
02 - Apr | abcd
02 - Apr | qwer
02 - Apr | fsdfx
06 - Apr | vsdc
07 - Apr | vsdv
07 - Apr | fpow
```

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
date col | Desc | Result
02 - Apr | abcd | 1 
02 - Apr | qwer | 1
02 - Apr | fsdfx | 1
06 - Apr | vsdc | 2 
07 - Apr | vsdv | 3
07 - Apr | fpow | 3
```

Comment: provide more details with your data and table schema

Comment: Post desired output.

Comment: You mean an incrementing number for each date?

Answer (score 1):

```
select
t.*
, @n := if(@prev != `date col`, @n + 1, @n) as result
, @prev := `date col`
from
t
, (select @prev := null, @n := 1) v
order by `date col`
```

- see it working live in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/595a0/2/0)

The logic is this:

This cross-joined query

```
, (select @prev := null, @n := 1) v
```

initializes the variables.

Then in the `select` clause, we first check, if the date differs from the previous row. If yes, increment the variable.
In the next line, we assign the value of the current row to the variable. Therefore, when the select clause is processed again, in the first line it has the "previous" value, in the next line the current value is assigned.

The `order by` clause is there, because there's no order in a relational database unless you specify it. Omit it and you will get wrong results.

Answer (score 0):

you need an aggregate together with `group by` depending on the semantics of "result": min, max, avg, sum - like:

```
SELECT sum(Result) from tab1 group by date_col
```